# unable to register node to hub in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

My **hub is working successfully** and running

```
    java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub -port 5555
```

my node command

```
  java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role webdriver –hub http://localhost:5555/gridhost/register -port 7621
```

but **unable to  register my  node** forbidden + for + proxy the hub is down or not responding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

Assuming that you have a requirement to run the Selenium Grid Hub on port `5555`, you have to consider the fact that by default Selenium Grid Node runs on port `5555`. As you are setting up the Hub & Node both on your localhost and have started the Hub on port `5555`, you have to consider configuring the node to run on some other port other than 5555. That will solve your issue.

If running the Selenium Grid Hub on port `5555` is not a mandatory requirement, then you can start the Selenium Grid Hub on the default port (port `4444`) or any other port , e.g. port `5786`

### Here are the steps for your reference:

1. Start the Selenium Grid Server (on port `5786`):

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role hub -port 5786
   ```
2. The following logs confirms your Selenium Grid Hub is running properly:

   ```
   2017-06-05 12:22:03.092:INFO:osjs.Server:main: Started @1917ms
   12:22:03.093 INFO - Nodes should register to http://192.168.0.101:5786/grid/register/
   12:22:03.094 INFO - Selenium Grid hub is up and running
   ```
3. Access the Selenium Grid Console through the URL:

   ```
   http://localhost:5786/grid/console
   ```
4. Start the Selenium Grid Node:

   ```
   java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:5786/grid/register
   ```
5. The following logs confirms your Selenium Grid Node is running properly:

   ```
   12:49:46.805 INFO - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
   12:49:46.927 INFO - Registering the node to the hub: http://localhost:5786/grid/register
   12:49:47.166 INFO - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
   ```
6. Access the Selenium Grid Console through the console URL to see the registered Node:

   ```
   http://localhost:5786/grid/console
   ```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Answer (score 0):

Try another port:

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role hub -port 4444

then

> java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar -role webdriver –hub
>   http://localhost:4444/gridhost/register -port 7621

It work for me

Answer (score 0):

The registration URL should not be `http://localhost:5555/gridhost/register`.

Please change it to `http://localhost:5555/grid/register` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

follow this steps to UP

```
java -jar selenium-server-<version>.jar standalone
```

then do

```
java -jar selenium-server-<version>.jar hub
```